# How can a shape with curved sides be drawn in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, graphics, drawing

In Objective-C, how do I draw a 2D shape similar to the one pictured [here](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/S8xtvqsna-8xA1GhDUR-6eOm7a2r4c5uDXwdXo00dOQ?feat=directlink)?  (sorry could not embed image).
Thanks!
-appleHap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa has a number of primitives for 2D drawing. You'll want to check out the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), specifically the section on [paths](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Paths/Paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH206-BBCHFJJG), which will detail the use of `NSBezierPath` to draw such shapes.